# Dominant Pole Approximation for loop gain

Tags: control-system, loop-gain, closed-loop

I have the following loop transfer function for a unity feedback system: [image: loop gain]

I understand that the \$(s+2)\$ term becomes \$2\$, but what happens to the \$s\$ ?

Comment: Why do you understand that when s is a variable.

Comment: @Andyaka I am not sure to be honest

Comment: If s+2 becomes 2 then s = 0.

Comment: This is a rather unusual situation for the dominant pole approximation. Are you sure you have the problem statement correct? If this approximation would be followed by a root locus analysis, it would seem very hazardous. You can't count on those non-dominant poles to stay non-dominant when the gain K is increased. But if you plowed ahead anyway, it would seem that the dominant pole should be the s=0 pole, and so it remains in \$L(s)\$ , while the other three poles are approximated by taking only their influence on the gain (i.e. plugging in \$s=0\$ to those factors).

Answer (score 2):

The numerator and denominator part of the transfer function show where the zeros and poles are respectively placed. The zero locations are determined, by finding the `s` value in the numerator which would lead to a closed loop response equal to 0. And, the pole locations are determined, by finding the `s` values in the denominator which would lead to a closed loop response approaching infinite.

In your case, the system has no zeros (numerator has no `s`). And by inspection you can determine that it has 2 real poles and one complex pole.

Real pole 1: If the first `s` is set to 0, the numerator becomes zero, hence the transfer function will approach infinite, meaning that you have a pole at the origin \$\omega=0 rad/s\$.

Real pole 2: If the second `s` is set to -2 , the transfer function will also approach infinite, meaning that you have a pole at the origin \$\omega=2 rad/s\$.

Complex pole: If the last equation is solved for `s`, it yields \$s= 2\pm i\$, which also make the transfer function approach infinite..

Just to to have a graphical representation, you can see the bode plot of your transfer function in the following diagram (\$K=1\$):

[image]